# SQL Server : query to copy one row to another table without identity

Tags: sql-server, copy, row

I have two tables with identical but unknown structure. Unknown because the query I need is going to be executed on multiple table pairs which are different from each other.

Table 1 has a few rows, Table 2 has many rows. What I would need to do is to copy a row based on the ID (identity) to the second table, but not specifying the identity on the insert statement since it will be already used on the destination table. So the new table should have the same row, but with different ID. I would like to do this with a single query.

Example:

Table 1:

```
ID    mycol1
--------------
1     10
2     423
3     5345
4     ew3
```

Table 2:

```
ID     mycol2
--------------
.      ..
529    103
530    652
531    sa3
```

Desired result: copy the line with ID 2 from table1 to table2 (new ID on table 2)

```
ID      mycol2
---------------
...     ...
529     103
530     652
531     sa3
532     423
```

This is a sample table with invented columns, but the query should work on any table with any structure. Every table will have the column "ID" as identity. I know how to do it with known columns, but have no idea on how to do it if the structure of the table is totally unknown.

Comment: So you would have a particular primary key ID from table1, and you need to copy the rest of the row into table2, and the relevant column names are the same in each table?

Comment: yes, exactly.. same column names on both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic SQL. Please be careful, as dynamic SQL can be difficult to write correctly, and prone to SQL injection if not done right.

**Make sure to parameterize properly.**

The table names must be embedded directly in the dynamic code, use `QUOTENAME` for this.

The `@id` parameter can be passed all the way through. Use `EXEC sp_executesql`, and you need to pass a string parameter to it, describing the actual parameters you are passing.

```sql
DECLARE @source nvarchar(128) = N'table1';
DECLARE @dest nvarchar(128) = N'table2';
DECLARE @id int = 123;

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max) =
(SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(c.name) AS nvarchar(max)), N', ')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@source)
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
N'INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(@target) + N'
    (' + @cols + N')' + N'
SELECT ' + @cols + N'
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@source) + N' AS t
WHERE t.id = @id;
';

-- PRINT @sql    -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@id int',
    @id = @id;
```